# Statistics of Installation of my app in Apple App Analytics

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, analytics, itunesconnect-analytics

I'm wondering, if it's possible to get a overview about the Installations on active devices, splitted by versions like I can do it in the google play console.

[image]

Comment: Try FireBase [Add Firebase to your iOS project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Comment: With Firebase I can just see the Update when the user opens the App..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can! But all data is "opt-in" only and usually captures something like 20-30% of your users.

[image]

You can see how many users agreed to share the data by clicking on the question mark next to "About App Analytics Data" in the top right corner

[image]

Comment: Ah cool, thank you. And this isn't just from the people which opened the App after updating?

Comment: Installations are defined as: "The total number of times your app has been installed on an iOS device with iOS 8 and tvOS 9 or later. Re-downloads on the same device, downloads to multiple devices sharing the same Apple ID, and Family Sharing installations are included. (Updates not included)"